# haralyzer library in python

Tags: python, har

I'm trying to use this part of my code with a for loop but I get this error and I do not understand why without a loop it is working perfectly.

```
sites=['altervista.org', 'amazon.it', 'ansa.it']
for num in range(0,3):
  y=sites[num]+'.har'
  with open(y, 'r') as f:
     har_parser = HarParser(json.loads(f.read()))
  data= har_parser.har_data
```

and I'm getting this error:\

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c5779b6aa6f7> in <module>
      2     y=sites[num]+'.har'
      3     with open(y, 'r') as f:
----> 4         har_parser = HarParser(json.loads(f.read()))
      5     data= har_parser.har_data
      6     url=[]

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'loads'
```

what is the problem???

Comment: For some reason, `json` is an integer. Your code probably has a line like `json = <an integer>`

Comment: share more code - make sure you dont have code like: `json = 5` ...

Comment: you were right my code was long and at some parts I starter to name my parameter jason because I was looking for a jason code.